# Users without full editing privileges are unable to edit their own posts or community wiki posts when the suggested edit queue is full

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

Someone just [complained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386905/377214) that they were unable to make an edit to their own post because the suggested edit queue was full on the site. This action used to work perfectly fine before, as edits to one's own posts are binding and don't count toward the cap of pending edits. Initially, I suspected they had accidentally created a second account or were somehow logged out, causing the system to not identify the post as their own. However, after following the link to their answer, I saw they had also posted a comment there about it through the same account (confirmed by user ID) that they couldn't edit their own post.

After attempting to reproduce myself, I can confirm that **users without full editing privileges can't make binding edits to their own posts if the suggested edit queue is full**. I also thought further to test with community wiki posts, and can confirm that the same is true for them.

This used to work just fine in the past: one could still make binding edits to posts even when the suggested edit queue was full if they had the right to do so on that specific post (own post or community wiki post where the user has the "edit community wiki" privilege).

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Related report on MSO: [Full edit queue blocking edits on own post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423311). In a comment Ivar said that you might also get blocked *with full editing privilege*

Comment: @VLAZ Based on their comments I'm guessing it applies to everyone when using the separate editor page. However, for users with enough reputation to edit, they can use the inline editor which doesn't seem to have the bug (I can't test for sure).

Comment: It also happens when trying to add a tag wiki, even on a site where the edit queue is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the report - we're shipping a fix soon.  Our goal was to provide a continuity of experience for people beginning an edit when the queue wasn't full, to reserve them a slot while on the edit page in case the edit queue filled up in the meantime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  We've rolled back changes intended to [allow edits which have already started even when queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398145/1366033), which reserved a slot for people who began an edit when the review queue was under capacity until they finished their edit. Sorry for the disruption